# TestNG plugin for Eclipse doesn't support customListener now?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, testng

In Eclipse Europa version, I had an option in testNG properties to specify the customListener class name that overrides default listener. I don't find that option in any other version of Eclipse? Is there any other way by which I can specify the customListener class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option was removed a [while back](http://groups.google.com/group/testng-users/browse_thread/thread/1911cdf726890b71)  in favor of specifying listeners and other configuration via a template testng.xml file that can be specified in Eclipse. Here is some documentation showing how to specify the testng.xml file: [TestNG listeners documentation](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html#eclipse-listeners).